# TinyTds fails to connect to azure on Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, tiny-tds

I'm trying to connect to a Azure SQL database using tiny-tds gem on ruby 2.2.3. I installed `freetds-dev` and `freetds-bin` and everything seems to work just fine there.

```
tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                        Version: freetds v0.91
         freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 4.2
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: yes
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: yes
```

and doing

```
TDSVER=7.1 tsql -U xxxxx -P xxxxx -H mydatabase.database.windows.net -p 1433
```

connects just fine (I get a prompt).

I installed tiny_tds gem:

```
/home/avril14th/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0
```

and tried to connect

```
avril14th@avril14th:~/src/white2$ pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'tiny_tds'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'xxxx', password: 'xxxxx', host: 'xxxxx.database.windows.net', :azure => true
TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection failed
```

I've tried a lot of other combinations of parameters, as described at tiny_tds [github page](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#tinytdsclient-usage) and none worked.

Any help is appreciated. I've been trying at this for over 5 hours now...What puzzles me is that it always fails instantly so it's not a question of timeout.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the version of TinyTDS, it has supported Azure for some time. The issue is how FreeTDS is compiled. It is lacking being compiled with OpenSSL support which is required by Azure. When done, you will see `OpenSSL: yes` in your output from `tsql -C` above.

We talk about this in our [Using TinyTDS with Azure](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#using-tinytds-with-azure) section of the readme.

**ADDED:** The reason TinyTDS 1.0 in master branch can connect is due to that version compiling OpenSSL and FreeTDS locally. That is a new feature that is not yet ready for public consumption yet. Depending on your needs and usage of system level FreeTDS, use either or... but the answer is still correct, the reason you could not use v0.7 for Azure is due to your system FreeTDS not having OpenSSL linked.

Comment: Well, at the moment and as displayed above, I have no `OpenSSL : yes` in `tsql -C` and yet I connect to Azure just fine with TinyTds. How can it be?

Comment: @muichkine - so are you able to connect to your database now?

Comment: @AndreaLam yes. I used TinyTds's gem master on github (1.0.0.beta1) instead of latest released one (0.7).